# execute DBMS_AQADM changeset fails - Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Tags: liquibase

I'm having trouble with the following Liquibase changeset

```
- changeSet:
id: 25
author: My_User
comment: "some comment"
objectQuotingStrategy: LEGACY
runAlways: true
changes:
- sql:
    dbms: oracle
    endDelimiter: ;
    splitStatements: true
    sql: execute DBMS_AQADM.GRANT_QUEUE_PRIVILEGE ('ALL', 'MY_SCHEMA.Q_ARCHIVECUST_REQUESTS', 'my_role')
    stripComments: true
```

when i run it i get the following error

```
20:56:25.190 DEBUG [liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet]: Reading ChangeSet: common.yaml::25::My_User
20:56:25.191 DEBUG [liquibase.database.core.OracleDatabase]: Executing Statement: execute DBMS_AQADM.GRANT_QUEUE_PRIVILEGE ('ALL', 'MY_SCHEMA.Q_ARCHIVECUST_REQUESTS', 'my_role')
20:56:25.191 INFO  [liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor]: execute DBMS_AQADM.GRANT_QUEUE_PRIVILEGE ('ALL', 'MY_SCHEMA.Q_ARCHIVECUST_REQUESTS', 'my_role')
20:56:25.329 ERROR [liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet]: Change Set common.yaml::25::My_User failed.  Error: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
  [Failed SQL: (900) execute DBMS_AQADM.GRANT_QUEUE_PRIVILEGE ('ALL', 'MY_SCHEMA.Q_ARCHIVECUST_REQUESTS', 'my_role')]
```

I can run the statement find in SQL Developer.

I'd be grateful for some advice

Comment: When you run it in SQL Developer, do you have the execute wrapped in a BEGIN / END statement?

Comment: no, i simply run it as
`execute DBMS_AQADM.GRANT_QUEUE_PRIVILEGE ('ALL', 'MY_SCHEMA.Q_ARCHIVECUST_REQUESTS', 'my_role');`

Comment: I am probably using a different version of Liquibase but I use 'call' instead of 'execute'.

Comment: @Stilgar using 'call' instead of 'execute' did the trick. Thanks!
I don't know if you want to propose this as an answer and I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Ok, others may find it helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The liquibase implementation I use is XML-Based and a snippet of the presentation code would look something like the following; CALL instead of EXECUTE.

```
...
<changeSet id="Umpity-Fratz-01" author="Myself">
    <sql splitStatements="true" stripComments="false">
        <![CDATA[
            CALL Owner.Procedure(p_Parameter_01 => 'xyz');
        ]]>
    </sql>    
</changeSet>
....
```